# Pass output of all interactive commands to less?

Tags: bash, less

In interactive bash session, is there a way to pass output of all commands to less? As if all commands typed in bash were followed by  `| less -RF`? Sort of like setting `pager=less -RF` in `my.cnf` for mysql CLI client.

Comment: I'd say the *interactive* commands (such as `less`, `vi`, shells, `nslookup`, `gdb`..., all the ones you *interact* with) are the ones you would *not* want to pipe to `less` as then you wouldn't be able to interact with them anymore (as `less` takes the user's input).

Comment: OK, I didn't express myself clearly. What I meant was all commands specified on interactive shell. So if I type `ls -l` on the shell it's as if I typed `ls -l | less -RF`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like the following to do it:

```
less_all_commands(){
  while read -ra c;do 
    "${c[@]}"|less; 
  done; 
}
```

You execute this function, all your commands will be piped to `less`.
Exit this function (`Ctrl + C`), you are back to your normal shell environment.